# Module cordova/exec/proxy not found using Cordova phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-3

I am new to Cordova and Phonegap and I am trying to develop a simple application that creates a contact and run it on my Android ([looking at this example](http://neophob.com/2013/08/phonegap-3-for-dummies-part-1-setup-and-a-first-example/))
I got my application loaded on my phone, my app is initialized (event initialize has been received) but before any other event I receive this exeception:

```
05-07 17:52:17.870: E/Web Console(22339): Uncaught module cordova/exec/proxy not found at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:55
```

Here is my **index.js**

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    console.log(" bindEvents ...");
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
     console.log("onDeviceReady ...");
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    var myContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName":"Test User"});
    myContact.note = "this contact has a note.";
    console.log("the contact, " + myContact.displayName + ", note: " + myContact.note);
    app.receivedEvent("contactcreated");
    myContact.save(app.onContactSaveSuccess,app.onContactSaveError);
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    console.log("receivedEvent ...");
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
},

onContactSaveSuccess: function(contact) {
    console.log("onContactSaveSuccess ...");
    window.alert("Save Success");
},

onContactSaveError: function(contact) {
    console.log("onContactSaveError ...");
    window.alert("Save Failed");
},
```

};

**Questions:**

2. what is the **cordova exec proxy** module?
3. how is possible to solve it?

Here is my cordova version: 3.1.0-0.2.0